# Why do I get "No routes matches post"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am not quite sure why I get this error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/transactions/new"
```

This is my config file:

```
TwerkApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "transactions/new"
  resources :transactions
```

This is my controller:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @transaction = Transaction.new(current_user.email, 100.0, params[:transaction])
  end

  def create
    @transaction = Transaction.new(current_user.email, 100.0, params[:transaction])
    if @transaction.charge
      flash[:success] = 'Thanks for the moolah!'
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash[:error] = @transaction.errors.first
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

This is the new transaction form:

```
= form_for :transaction do |f|
  = label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number"
  = text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil, :value => "4111111111111111", class: "cc-number"
  %p
  = label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)"
  = text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil, :value => "123", class: "cc-csc"
  %p
  = label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration"
  = select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, class: "cc-em"}
  = select_year Date.new(2020), {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, class: "cc-ey"}
  %br
  = f.submit
```

And the rake routes:

```
      transactions GET    /transactions(.:format)              transactions#index
                   POST   /transactions(.:format)              transactions#create
   new_transaction GET    /transactions/new(.:format)          transactions#new
  edit_transaction GET    /transactions/:id/edit(.:format)     transactions#edit
       transaction GET    /transactions/:id(.:format)          transactions#show
                   PUT    /transactions/:id(.:format)          transactions#update
                   DELETE /transactions/:id(.:format)          transactions#destroy
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't get why you have a `get "transactions/new"` in your routes, when `resources :transactions` already generated this route.
2. There is no `[POST] "/transactions/new"`, there is only one `GET    /transactions/new(.:format)`.
3. You should use the instance instead of a symbol in the form_for:

   ```
   = form_for @transaction do |f|
   ```

   It will send a POST request to `/transactions`.

Answer (score 1):

The `new` method in the controller should be updated as follows:

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @transaction = Transaction.new
  end
```

The `TransactionsController#create` method also needs to be updated.  The `Transaction#new` method is being passed three arguments, but it should only take a single hash as an argument.  I'm not sure what the fields are in your database, but something like this should work:

```
@transaction = Transaction.new({ email: current_user.email, money: 100.0 }.merge(params[:transaction]))
```

The form should be updated as well:

```
= form_for :transaction do |f|
  = f.label :card_number, "Credit Card Number"
  = f.text_field :card_number
```